# How best can I write an sql statement to be checking the values properly?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to write an sql statement that will be checking if the a record exits in the table and the sql statement uses two  values or parameters  to check if the record exist. Now the problem I have is that it is not working according or in other words it is not pairing these checks properly. The  sql statement is as follows;

This statement should check a lot of values at a time without putting variables

```
Select * from table_D where 
   field_X NOT IN (select field_X from  table_G) and 
   field_J NOT IN (select field_J from table_G)
```

However, this statement is not working according sometimes it is showing that  there is no record that meets this selection criteria when the record is there. How can I do it? How can I refine it?

Comment: I think your data isn't identical, or perhaps you have NULL values. Can you copy/paste the rows from the 3 tables you think should show up.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT *
    FROM table_D d
    WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT NULL
                         FROM table_G g
                         WHERE g.field_X = d.field_X
                             AND g.field_J = d.field_J);
```

Comment: I dunno, the `SELECT NULL` initially gave me pause ("what happens if the row returns `null` - does it not exist?").  I think you're right (although I can't test it - DB2 rejects this), but is there some condition that makes this more performant than using a constant value - `SELECT '1'`, or something?

Comment: @X-Zero: The choice of using `SELECT NULL` is arbitary. There should be no difference if you'd prefer to use `SELECT 1` instead.

Comment: I use select * because I don't like the arbitrary constant. It truly doesn't matter though.

Answer (score 0):

Try the Exists function

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT Name from table WHERE FName ='smith')
BEGIN

END
```